# Is Cloud Foundry ready for production?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm interested in hosting my own instance of Cloud Foundry v2 and whant to know - is it really ready to be used in production, are there any real bugs with it yet?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow; any answers will be completely opinion-based, and (assuming Cloud Foundry isn't ready for production) once Cloud Foundry *is* ready for production, this question will no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a small research and figured that there are quite a few problems:

- Not complete SSL support, only router-terminated
- Quite few supported services ()
- Lots of small bugs and issues

So I came to a conclusion that I will not use it yet.